# Not able to see views once activity is restarted in android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing a strange issue, I am trying to implement an activity with 6 types of different layouts, only one will be visible at a time based on layout type and others will be hidden

So the flow is a Handler shows every type/view after 20 seconds and after say n times the activity finishes.

Now the problem is if I restart the activity I am not able to see any of the views

**Layout file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout style="@style/RelParent"
            android:id="@+id/rel_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<include
    android:id="@+id/rel_1"
    layout="@layout/layout_1"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/rel_2"
    layout="@layout/layout_2"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/rel_3"
    layout="@layout/layout_3"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/rel_4"
    layout="@layout/layout_4"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/rel_5"
    layout="@layout/layout_5"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/rel_6
    layout="@layout/layout_6"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity Code:**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<Model> mModels;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate, starting quiz");
    initLayoutTypeMap();
    hideAllLayouts();
mModels = //getDataFromDB;
    mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);
}


private void initLayoutTypeMap() {
    mTypeLayoutMap = new HashMap<>();
    mTypeLayoutMap.put(type1, relType1);
    mTypeLayoutMap.put(type2, relType2);
    mTypeLayoutMap.put(type3, relType3);
    mTypeLayoutMap.put(type4, relType4);
    mTypeLayoutMap.put(type5, relType5);
    mTypeLayoutMap.put(type6, relType6);
}

private void startNew(int id) {
 Model model = mModels.get(id);
 showLayout(model.getType);
 showLayout(type);
 //Do all the data showing on views
}

private void showLayout(String type) {
    mTypeLayoutMap.get(type).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (id <= mModels.size()) {
            hideAllLayouts();
            clearAll();
            startNew(id);
            id++;
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 20000);
        } else {
            hideAllLayouts();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
            finish();
          }
      }
  };
}
```

**For the first iteration everything works as expected. But once I finish this activity and try to start it again no view is visible**

Comment: Can you please show your whole code? There are some methods missing from your onCreate()  like hideAllLayouts()?

Answer (score 1):

move your handler code to `onResume()` from `onCreate()` like

```
    @Override
    public void onResume(){

    if(mTypeLayoutMap  == null){
     initLayoutTypeMap();
    }
        hideAllLayouts();
    if(mModel == null){
    mModels = //getDataFromDB;
    }

    if(mHandler == null){
     mHandler = new Handler();
    }

mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);
}
```

and also declare your id = 1 before `finish()` so it will again iterate .

```
 else {
            hideAllLayouts();
           id=1;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
            finish();
          }
```

Comment: I tried this approach but doesn't work, it doesn't show any of the six layouts.